# How to generate and set `JWT_SECRET` and `JWT_EXPIRATION_TIME` in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, secret-key

When I run my server,I suffered following errors.

`Error: Config validation error: "JWT_SECRET" is required. "JWT_EXPIRATION_TIME" is required`

Therefore I must set JWT secret key and so on.

I'd like to know how to set `JWT_SECRET`.But I couldn't figure out how to generate and set them.

I set`.env` file,I must configure some of variables in them.

my`.env` file is like following.

`.env`

```
JWT_SECRET=
JWT_EXPIRATION_TIME=
```

If someone know good way to generate `SECRET` please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: put a value after `=`

Comment: Thanks, As I beginner,are there any way to generate value(secret key?) ? I search for the way to achieve them.

Comment: typing on the keyboard is one way - you know, it's secret, so you can type in the name of your favourite ice cream flavour, pet dog and favourite child if you want :p - or a randomly generated GUID ... secrets just have to be long, not random

Comment: The secret is not something you generate. It is something you (human) make. It is basically a password. So use any appropriate way you use for generating passwords that you care about like your bank account: randomly mashing keyboard, diceware, a list of words etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned by @Arya and @JaromandaX, you have to type something after `JWT_SECRET` something like this `JWT_SECRET=yourfavoritecolor` and `JWT_EXPIRATION_TIME=3600`. You can call them in your code with `process.env.JWT_SECRET` and `process.env.JWT_EXPIRATION_TIME`.

Check this article on JWT-[Right way of implementing JWT](https://medium.com/@siddharthac6/json-web-token-jwt-the-right-way-of-implementing-with-node-js-65b8915d550e)

Answer (score 12):

You can generate a token in the console by running this command:

```
node -e "console.log(require('crypto').randomBytes(32).toString('hex'));"
```

then add the generated token to your `.env` file

Answer (score 3):

It's Very simple you just have  to add this to your `.env` file

```
JWT_SECRET=  any text or number you want to add here to create jwt Token
JWT_EXPIRATION_TIME= you have to specify time limit like you want thattoken expire in 24 hours you have to add  60 * 60 * 24 or  86400 // 24 hours
```

and there is no other way to generate `secrert`

Answer (score 3):

The other users have already answered the question of how to set JWT_SECRET, and I'll add how to generate it. @slebetman gave good advice to generate the string using password generators (they exist both separately and as part of most password managers). For this purpose, I usually use the following command, which I simply enter into the terminal and copy it to the .env file:

```sh
openssl rand -base64 172 | tr -d '\ n'
```

Where `172` is the number of characters in the generated string (choose the one you want).

I hope it will be helpful :)